# How can Google Drive search show the containing folder name?

Tags: google-drive

Why doesn't Drive search show the containing folder name? All it does is give me a list of items matching the query and I have to go inside each item to see its current location.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the information icon (i) to open the information panel on the right-hand side.   The (i) icon may be found at the top toolbar of the search results.
2. There are two tabs, Details and Activity.  Click on Details to make it active.
3. When you scroll down through the search list on the left the location for each file shows in the information panel, in the field marked Location.  Consequently, you do not need to go inside each item.